# uso de Arraylist en java

Tags: java, arraylist

[image: titulo del ejercicio]

Necesito ayuda con este ejercicio de java, tengo el código, le he dado mil vueltas y no encuentro el error, al poner la entrada en mi id sale la salida buena, pero al introducir el código en la pagina me sale error. Lo tengo que entregar para mañana sino suspendo la evaluación, aquí pongo el código. Agradezco mucho la ayuda.
He probado mirando el código de arriba a abajo un montón y no encuentro el error, mi profe se pensaba que estaba bien, necesito que acepte el código en la pagina. no se porque no me deja publicarlo porque pone que mi publicacion es mayormente codigo

````
public class padel {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, Integer> resultado = new HashMap<>();
        String categoria;
        int partJugados;
        do {
            categoria = sc.nextLine();
            if (!categoria.equals("FIN")) {
                partJugados = addPuntos(resultado);
                calcularGanador(resultado, partJugados);
            }
        } while (!categoria.equals("FIN"));
    }
    
    public static int addPuntos(Map<String, Integer> resultado) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String equipoCasa, equipoVisitante;
        int puntosCasa, puntosVisitante, partidos = 0;
        resultado.clear();
        do {
            equipoCasa = sc.next();
            if (!equipoCasa.equals("FIN")) {
                puntosCasa = sc.nextInt();
                equipoVisitante = sc.next();
                puntosVisitante = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine(); 
                if (puntosCasa > puntosVisitante) {
                    sumaPuntos(resultado, equipoCasa, equipoVisitante);
                } else {
                    
                }
                partidos++;
            } else{
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        } while (!equipoCasa.equals("FIN"));
        return partidos;
    }
      
    public static void sumaPuntos(Map<String, Integer> resultado, String ganador, String perdedor) {
        
        if (resultado.containsKey(ganador)) {
            resultado.put(ganador, resultado.get(ganador) + 2);
        } else {
            resultado.put(ganador, 2);
        }
        if (resultado.containsKey(perdedor)) {
            resultado.put(perdedor, resultado.get(perdedor) + 1);
        } else {
            resultado.put(perdedor, 1);
        }
    }
    
    public static void calcularGanador(Map<String, Integer> resultado, int partJugados){
        int partFaltan = (resultado.size() * (resultado.size() - 1) - partJugados);
        String primero = "", segundo = "";
        int puntos1 = 0, puntos2 = 0;
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : resultado.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Integer val = entry.getValue();      
            if (puntos1 < val) {
                primero = key;
                puntos1 = val;
            }
        }
        resultado.remove(primero);
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : resultado.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Integer val = entry.getValue();
            
            if (puntos2 < val) {
                segundo = key;
                puntos2 = val;
            }
        }
        if (puntos1 == puntos2) {
            System.out.println("EMPATE " + partFaltan);
        } else {
            System.out.println(primero + partFaltan);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Cuál es la salida del programa actualmente?

Comment: el problema es que en mi id la salida del programa es la correcta, pero a la hora de meter el código en la pagina de acepta el reto me sale error, que pone wrong anwser

Comment: Ya, pero ese *wrong anwser*, es un error del código, que falla y te sale toda una traza de error, es un error de la lógica de tu programa en alguna parte, que muestra dicho mensaje. Debes ponernos en contexto para que podamos ayudarte mejor, agregando a la pregunta el mensaje de error, cualquiera que sea. Si es una traza de error, ponla como texto y como nota, así SO no se quejará de que es demasiado código.

Comment: el wrong anwser me sale en la pagina pero en el id no me sale que este mal, entonces en la pagina no sale nada mas que wrong anwser,en la pagina probara mas casos, ya que yo solo he probado ese

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres cuando hablas de *página* ¿?

Comment: la pagina se llama acepta el reto

Comment: perdón no lo dije

Answer (score -1):

ya lo he conseguido era el equalsignorecase

Comment: Hola santiago, me alegra que encontraras una solución al problema. ¿Podrías añadir algo más información a la respuesta? Tal y como está ahora no queda claro qué es `equalsgnorecase` o dónde iría en el código.

Comment: no puede ser, en este código esta bien XD, no se porque en este codigo no esta pero en el mío original tenia para que cuando pusieras fin se ejecutara el codigo, pues tenia equalsgnorecase y era solo equals lol

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/404238)